# some css properties not working with media queries

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, media-queries

When I try to change the width and border-color property of a Bootstrap 4 card depending on the screen width it gets the width and border-color value from the default one.

Default CSS:

```
#ongoing-mobile-tournament.card{
    width: 75%;
    border-color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

Using media queries:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
    #ongoing-mobile-tournament.card{
        width: 25%;
        border-color: blue;
        display: none;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: So move the media queries to the end of your css file?

Comment: Thanks @AlonEitan, that worked. Can you explain the reason for the issue?

Comment: Because AFAIK using media queries doesn't affect the selector priority, so by moving the media query style part to the bottom you make its priority higher